# what does "? 1 : 0" mean

Tags: c, bitwise-operators

I don't understand what the third line is trying  to accomplish. I just recently learned bit-wise operators. It would be great if someone could walk me though the last two lines. I understand shift operator but i.t.o the shift operator I'm not entirely sure of what it means.

```
    void create(uint8_t bInt[], int64_t num){
      for (int pos = 0; pos < 32; pos++){ 
        bInt[pos] = (num & mask) ? 1 : 0;
        mask = mask << 1;
         }
       }
```

For this assignment, we're using 32-element array of uint8_t values to represent 32 bit integers. For example, the integer 84193 in binary is 0....0001 0100 1000 1110 0001. In bInt[], it would be stored as 
1000 0111 0001 0010 1000 0000....0.  Thank you for your time

Comment: It's called conditional operator: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:

Comment: Ternary operator: if (this condition) return 1 else return 0;

Comment: You can replace `(num & mask) ? 1 : 0` with `(num & mask) != 0` or `!!(num & mask)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`?:` is a [ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:). `(num & mask) ? 1 : 0;`

Think of it like this:

```
if( (num & mask) ) {
    bInt[pos] = 1
} else {
    bInt[pos] = 0
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is ternary operator and also used in some other language like - java, c++. It is a replacement of short form `if-then-else`. It works like below -

```
expression ? if_true_then_process_it : or_process_it
```

Comment: Hmm.. Avoid repeating answers already given in repose to a question. While correct, self, provided the exact answer 5 minutes before your response. Sometimes, it is unavoidable, (e.g. two people answer at the same time), but it is something that should be avoided if possible.